# Need help walking through logic of this code

Tags: python

I'm pretty new with Python and programming in general, so excuse the lack of "fu". :)

I'm having trouble understanding this class call:

## snippet

```
class bar:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __add__(self, b):
        s = self.a + b.a
        return s
```

## end snippet

So, from the interpreter, if I issue:

```
x = bar(10)
y = bar(20)
z = x + y
print(z)
```

I get '30' back. That's correct.

I see how self.a is created, but I don't understand how b.a is getting created to do the addition.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `x + y` it is actually translated to:

```
x.__add__(y)
```

Therefore, this method is called:

```
__add__(self, b)  # __add__(x, y)
```

Which results in:

```
s = x.a + y.a     # 30
return 30
```

Comment: Thank you! This coupled with the other two answers below helped a lot.

Comment: I have a small question. For `x.__add__(y)` it seems only `x`'s `__add__` is called, but actually both of `x`, `y` are called. @mishik

Comment: @zhangyangyu, order matters, yes. For `x+y` - `x.__add__(y)` is called, for `y+x` - `y.__add(x)__` is called.

Answer (score 3):

In this code, b.a isn't being created, it is being accessed. You're basically passing in y as the argument b, which already has an `a` attribute associated with it since it is an object of type `bar`. If you want to step through your code go to http://www.pythontutor.com

Comment: Slater - thanks, I was missing the + being the call to __add__ my second argument. This was a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`x = bar(a)` creates an object of the class `bar` with an a value of 'a'. Each `bar` object has a property/variable named `a`.

In `x + y`, the function `add` of x is called using `y` as the parameter.

So `b = y`, meaning `b.a = y.a = 20`.